# new to HTML, CSS and .svg. need assistance

Tags: html, css

I am self-teaching myself how to code HTML and I am super new to this (this is my first project.) There are lots of resources online that I am using and I've managed to figure things out as I go. However, I am encountering an issue: I have an .svg border around my page and then some text that I have added. Somehow the text has a white background that goes over the border and I want to eliminate this text background but I can't seem to figure out how. I have attached an image showing what it looks like and my code.
I'd appreciate any help or direction on how to resolve this. And as I am very very new to this, please explain it step by step as I am not familiar with any of the terminologies (for example, I still don't understand what div is lol)
Thanks in advance! :D

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF</title>
</head>

<style>
    html {
        background-image: url("border\ cleaned.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    body { 
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .title {
        padding-left: 160px;
        padding-top: 100px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .intro {
        padding-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
</style>

<body>

<h1 class="title">Portable
    <br>Digital
    <br>Format</h1>
<p class="intro">Portable Digital Format is a curated virtual space 
    <br>founded by Ahmad Saleh to showcasing creative
    talent
    <br>within the SWANA region.
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Comment: in your css block for body you are specifying that the background color should be `rgb(255, 255, 255)` Any element of your page within a <body> block will use this style when not told otherwise. If I'm understanding your question, I believe you wish to change this to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` or `transparent` so your text has no background color.